# How to place two figures with subigures side by side

Tags: graphics, positioning, subcaption

I want to display two images with multiple subfigures in a grid so that the subfigures go vertical as well as keeping the two images sort of separated. My current approach looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[draft=false, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a} 
        \caption{Image A}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[draft=false, width=\textwidth]{example-image-b} 
        \caption{Image B}
        \label{fig:1b}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \caption{Image Collection 1}
    \label{fig:Pasnatsch}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[draft=false, width=\textwidth]{example-image-c} 
        \caption{Image C}
        \label{fig:2a}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[draft=false, width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck} 
        \caption{Image D}
        \label{fig:2b}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \caption{Image Collection 2}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

which does place the second group of images on a new page. Also the main captions are not properly aligned (showing me how to align them left / right / center would be great to know).
An example project with the code above can be found at https://www.overleaf.com/read/rmkjzhqbbbpg

I also created an image to clarify what I want to achieve (bad quality, but I hope it makes it more understandable)

[image: what I want]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place each subgroup of subfigures (pun intended), along with the overall figure caption, in a separate `minipage` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0.25\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\textwidth} % or '[b]', if desired
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[draft=false, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a} 
        \caption{Image A}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \medskip % create some vertical separation
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[draft=false, width=\textwidth]{example-image-b} 
        \caption{Image B}
        \label{fig:1b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Image Collection 1}
    \label{fig:Pasnatsch}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\textwidth} % or '[b]', if desired
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[draft=false, width=\textwidth]{example-image-c} 
        \caption{Image C}
        \label{fig:2a}
    \end{subfigure}

    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[draft=false, width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck} 
        \caption{Image D}
        \label{fig:2b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Image Collection 2}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm :)